# OpenXava WITH play

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, openxava

I want to use the OpenXava scafolding system, with Play! framework (1.2.5 or 2.x).

This is because I need to do a prototype, and some requirements are easy to do with play, and others with OpenXava.

Someone did this? How I can do it? Tell me our experiences!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not so easy, because OpenXava based on Servlets and I assume Sessions. Play is stateless and don't use the servlet api. Play2 can only be deployed in a war-file on servlet3.0, play 1.2 can deploy as war on servlet 2.0-container.
It's not clear what you can easily do with openxava and what with play, however one approach could to be run 2 applications. Play is stateless so you can easily address a action with a url. So at least switching from openxava to play should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Play, but if you can deploy your play application in war format, just merge your play application with the OpenXava one.